# Insert single quotes in text file for use as SQL query that follows the open-parens using sed

Tags: sed

I have a *where* clause string in Unix file as below

```
where c1 in (a) and c2 in (a,b,c) and c3 in ()
```

Need Output as

```
where c1 in ('a') and c2 in ('a','b','c') and c3 in ('')
```

Would be great if some one can complete this.

Comment: Can you please [edit your post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/279304/edit) to provide sample input and output?  It's hard to tell what you're asking exactly.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -r "s/,/','/g; s/\(([^)]+)\)/('\1')/g"
```

Let's see how this changes the input you provided:

```
where c1 in (a) and c2 in (a,b,c) and c3 in ()
```

First, commas are wrapped in quotes (`s/,/','/g`):

```
where c1 in (a) and c2 in (a','b','c) and c3 in ()
```

Then we add quotes inside non-empty parens (`s/\(([^)]+)\)/('\1')/g`):

```
where c1 in ('a') and c2 in ('a','b','c') and c3 in ()
```

…which is the output you wanted.

Take care, as this regular expression might affect other lines in the ways you don't want.

Comment: Clever, I was thinking it would have to be done in a loop.

Comment: @Wildcard - if commas may occur outside those parens then you need to loop. This is something OP should clarify.

Comment: @Alex - Many Thanks, the above solution is working fine, How to edit the same if i want the single quotes when there's no text as well i.e.  where c1 in ('a') and c2 in ('a','b','c') and c3 in ('').

Comment: @sai, just change `+` to `*` in the last step.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with a loop:

```
sed -e ':top' -e 's/\([(,]\)\([^),'\'']\{1,\}\)\([),]\)/\1'"'\2'"'\3/;t top'
```

Or, using `-E`:

```
sed -E -e ':top' -e "s/([(,])([^),']+)([),])/\1'\2'\3/;t top"
```

Comment: @don_crissti, thanks.  I didn't realize it made a difference in portability.  It looks like neither is POSIX, but I see that BSD `sed` supports `-E` but not `-r`, while GNU `sed` supports both.

Comment: nice, but doesn't work if the input contains other sql code - e.g. `echo 'select z, y, x from d, e, f where c1 in (a) and c2 in (a,b,c) and c3 in ()' | sed -E -e ':top' -e "s/([(,])([^),']+)([),])/\1'\2'\3/;t top"` produces `select z,' y',' x from d',' e',' f where ...`.  The `sed` script shouldn't touch the select fields or the from tables, or anything else outside of `in (...)` (and maybe `values (...)`, but that would depend on the field type of the individual values).  This is a hard problem to solve, easier to just generate correct SQL in the first place.

Comment: now that i think about it, the comment about `values (...)` is also true of the values in an `in (...)` clause.  They should only be quoted if they're varchar or date types or similar, not numeric types.  To do it accurately, the script needs to know the data types.

Comment: @cas, I suspect you're overthinking it—as I read it, the Original Poster was just trying to avoid a huge amount of repetitive editing, not trying to automate the whole thing end to end.  But you have a good point; if you write an answer that addresses those issues I'd definitely vote for it.  :)

Comment: I don't think i am over-thinking it.  I'm speaking (writing) from years of personal experience doing exactly the kind of things that the OP is doing - trying to correct a simple generation of SQL with some fancy post-processing using `sed` or `awk`.  It turns out that it's actually much easier to write the script so that it generates correct sql code in the first place than to generate almost-correct sql and try to fix it.   If the OP reads the comments (i wrote them mostly for him to see, rather than you), he should now be aware of the potential flaws in this approach.

Comment: @cas Both the sed and perl parts of my answer seem to successfully parse your example of `select z, y, x from d, e, f where c1 in (a) and c2 in (a,b,c) and c3 in ()`. That is not to say that they are perfect; I'm sure there are ways to break my solutions. I also agree that it's better to generate the code you want/need from the start rather than try to transform it later.

Comment: @ryan, yep.  personally, I tend to just use `perl` with `DBI` or `SQL::Statement` etc.  or SQLFairy (http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/) (love the logo).    With a properly written prepared statement and place-holders you don't even need to care about quoting, these `perl` modules will automatically handle quoting for you as needed.  I have written numerous `sh`/`bash` mysql or psql scripts but it's **much** harder to get the sql commands right than in `perl`.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing in your file is a WHERE clause as described in your post, then this should do:

```
$ sed -r "s/(\(|,)([^ ),]+)(\)|,)/\1'\2'\3/g" <Filename>
where c1 in ('a') and c2 in ('a',b,'c') and c3 in ()
```

If your file is full of other data, like the rest of that SQL statement, or multiple SQL statements, then this may interfere with other text in that file.  Since `sed` does not have lookbehind/lookahead functionality, you might consider a safer alternative in `perl` (if your WHERE clauses are on separate lines from the rest of each SQL statement):

```
$ perl -ne "s/(\(|,)([^ ),]+)(\)|,)/\1'\2'\3/g if /where/; print;" <Filename>
where c1 in ('a') and c2 in ('a',b,'c') and c3 in ()
```